# Error when checking model input keras when predicting new results

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, word-embedding

I am trying to use a keras model I built on new data, except I have an input error when trying to predict the predictions.

Here's my code for the model:

```
def build_model(max_features, maxlen):
    """Build LSTM model"""
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(max_features, 128, input_length=maxlen))
    model.add(LSTM(128))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='rmsprop')

    return model
```

And my code to predict the output predictions of my new data:

```
LSTM_model = load_model('LSTMmodel.h5')
data = pickle.load(open('traindata.pkl', 'rb'))


#### LSTM ####

"""Run train/test on logistic regression model"""

# Extract data and labels
X = [x[1] for x in data]
labels = [x[0] for x in data]

# Generate a dictionary of valid characters
valid_chars = {x:idx+1 for idx, x in enumerate(set(''.join(X)))}

max_features = len(valid_chars) + 1
maxlen = np.max([len(x) for x in X])

# Convert characters to int and pad
X = [[valid_chars[y] for y in x] for x in X]
X = sequence.pad_sequences(X, maxlen=maxlen)

# Convert labels to 0-1
y = [0 if x == 'benign' else 1 for x in labels]


y_pred = LSTM_model.predict(X)
```

The error I get when running this code:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_1_input to have shape (57,) but got array with shape (36,)
```

My error comes from `maxlen` because for my training data, `maxlen=57` and with my new data, `maxlen=36`.

So I tried to set in my prediction code `maxlen=57` but then I get this error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: indices[31,53] = 38 is not in [0, 38)
     [[Node: embedding_1/embedding_lookup = GatherV2[Taxis=DT_INT32, Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](embedding_1/embeddings/read, embedding_1/Cast, embedding_1/embedding_lookup/axis)]]
```

What should I do in order to resolve these issues? Change my embedding layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either set the `input_length` of the Embedding layer to the maximum length you would see in the dataset, or just use the same `maxlen` value you used when constructing the model in `pad_sequences`. In that case any sequence shorter than `maxlen` would be padded and any sequence longer than `maxlen` would be truncated.

Further make sure that the features you use are the same in both train and test time (i.e. their numbers should not change).

Comment: I set maxlen value to 100 and now I don't have these errors anymore, thanks